# Get difference of unique and duplicate set - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, except

I have two similar data sets (table, view, CTE), one of which contains unique rows (guaranteed by `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`), the second contains duplicates (no primary key constraint involved).

### How can I get the *difference* of two data sets so that I only get the duplicates of the second set in MySql 8?

Say I have a table called Animals, which stores `NAME` and `SPECIES`.

```
 +---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
 +---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | ID      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
 | NAME    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | SPECIES | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 +---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

 ANIMALS
 +----+---------+-------------+
 | ID | NAME    | SPECIES     |
 +----+---------+-------------+
 |  1 | Lion    | Carnivorous |
 |  2 | Giraffe | Herbivores  |
 |  3 | Zebra   | Herbivores  |
 |  4 | Trutle  | Herbivores  |
 |  5 | Tiger   | Carnivorous |
 |  6 | Bear    | Carnivorous |
 +----+---------+-------------+
```

With that in place, I define the view `DUPLICATED`.

```
 CREATE VIEW DUPLICATED AS
     SELECT * FROM ANIMALS
     UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM ANIMALS WHERE SPECIES = "Carnivorous";
```

(Duplicates every Carnivorous in the set)

```
 DUPLICATED
 +---------+-------------+-----+
 | NAME    | SPECIES     | CNT |
 +---------+-------------+-----+
 | Lion    | Carnivorous |   2 |
 | Tiger   | Carnivorous |   2 |
 | Bear    | Carnivorous |   2 |
 | Giraffe | Herbivores  |   1 |
 | Zebra   | Herbivores  |   1 |
 | Trutle  | Herbivores  |   1 |
 +---------+-------------+-----+
```

Now I want to get the difference of `SELECT * FROM ANIMALS` and `DUPLICATED` or vice versa, essential getting all Carnivorous from `ANIMALS`.

Comment: Please put your own codes to better undrestand

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can group by whatever combination of fields that guarantee the uniqueness of a record in your result. you haven't provided your queries or your table's schema, so i will try to demonstrate this using a general example. you can get my drift and apply it to your query.

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY field1, field2, field3
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```